# Scraping links from a website asynchronously?

Tags: python, asynchronous, google-cloud-platform, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape internal links from a website currently with a depth of only 1. Here is the code I am using for it:

```py
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def clean_remove_duplicate(urls, complete_list, MAIN_URL): 
  temp = []
  for i in urls: 
    if i not in complete_list and i.find(MAIN_URL) != -1:
      complete_list.append(i) 
  
  return complete_list


def make_request_return_url(url, MAIN_DOMAIN):
      complete_list = []
      session = HTMLSession()
      response = session.get(url)
      try:
        response.html.render()
      except:
        pass
      soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, "html.parser")
      for a_tag in soup.findAll("a"):
        href = a_tag.attrs.get("href")
        if href == "" or href is None:
            # href empty tag
            continue
        href = urljoin(url, href)
        parsed_href = urlparse(href)
        href = parsed_href.scheme + "://" + parsed_href.netloc + parsed_href.path
       
       ##Make sure it is not an external link
        if href.find(MAIN_DOMAIN) != -1: 
          complete_list.append(href)
      
      return complete_list

MAIN_DOMAIN = "https://uwcmahindracollege.org/"

final_list_of_clearn_urls = []
urls_already_searched = []

s = make_request_return_url(MAIN_DOMAIN, MAIN_DOMAIN)
final_list_of_clearn_urls = clean_remove_duplicate(s, final_list_of_clearn_urls, MAIN_DOMAIN)

to_search = final_list_of_clearn_urls

for i in range(0, len(to_search)):
  print(i)
  current_url =  to_search[i]
  response = make_request_return_url(current_url, MAIN_DOMAIN)
  final_list_of_clearn_urls = clean_remove_duplicate(response, final_list_of_clearn_urls, MAIN_DOMAIN)
```

This scrapes about 150 unique URLs and takes about 28s. I am wondering how to can I make this asynchronous? I am eventually looking to deploy it into a GCP Cloud function. Hence, I am confused what is the best way to make it async and how to do it. For example, I have read that writing this with `scrapy` (which has async built in) can be difficult to use in cloud functions (I think because of twisted).

TL;DR: How can I make this **scraper** working asynchronously to improve the time it takes to complete it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `multiprocessing` to scrape multiple link simultaneously(parallelly):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
    
def scrape(url):
    #Scraper script

p = Pool(10)
# This “10” means that 10 URLs will be processed at the same time.
p.map(scrape, list_of_all_urls)
p.terminate()
p.join()
```

> Here we map function scrape with list_of_all_urls and Pool p will take care of executing each of them concurrently.This is similar to looping over list_of_all_urls in simple.py but here it is done concurrently. If number of URLs is 100 and we specify Pool(20), then it will take 5 iterations (100/20) and 20 URLs will be processed in one go.

**Two things to note**

1. The links are not executed in order. You can see order is 2,1,3… This is because of multiprocessing and time is saved by one process by not waiting for previous one to finish. This is called parallel execution.
2. This scrape very fast then normal. This difference grows very quickly when number of URLs increase which means that performance of multiprocessing script improves with large number of URLs.

You may visit [here](https://medium.datadriveninvestor.com/speed-up-web-scraping-using-multiprocessing-in-python-af434ff310c5) for more/detail information.

Comment: Is this multiprocessing approach actually faster considering scraping is I/O rather than CPU limited? 
 Thus, for web scraping multithreading is recommended (rather than multiprocessing) as explained by [Faster Web Scraping in Python](https://beckernick.github.io/faster-web-scraping-python/).

Answer (score 0):

You can use multithreading (since I/O limited) rather than multiprocessing (which is for CPU limited)

On my machine:

- 35 seconds for original version (with print statements removed)
- 14 seconds for multi-threaded version

**Multi-Threaded Version**

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
from urllib.parse import urlparse, urljoin
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import concurrent.futures

MAIN_DOMAIN = "https://uwcmahindracollege.org/"

def clean_remove_duplicate(urls, complete_list, MAIN_URL): 
  temp = []
  for i in urls: 
    if i not in complete_list and i.find(MAIN_URL) != -1:
      complete_list.append(i) 
  
  return complete_list


def make_request_return_url(url, main_domain = "https://uwcmahindracollege.org/"):
      complete_list = []
      session = HTMLSession()
      response = session.get(url)
      try:
        response.html.render()
      except:
        pass
      soup = BeautifulSoup(response.html.html, "html.parser")
      for a_tag in soup.findAll("a"):
        href = a_tag.attrs.get("href")
        if href == "" or href is None:
            # href empty tag
            continue
        href = urljoin(url, href)
        parsed_href = urlparse(href)
        href = parsed_href.scheme + "://" + parsed_href.netloc + parsed_href.path
       
       ##Make sure it is not an external link
        if href.find(main_domain) != -1: 
          complete_list.append(href)
      
      return complete_list

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t0 = time.time()
    
    final_list_of_clearn_urls = []
    urls_already_searched = []

    s = make_request_return_url(MAIN_DOMAIN, MAIN_DOMAIN)
    final_list_of_clearn_urls = clean_remove_duplicate(s, final_list_of_clearn_urls, MAIN_DOMAIN)

    to_search = final_list_of_clearn_urls
    
    MAX_THREADS = 30
    threads = min(MAX_THREADS, len(to_search))
    
    # Note: Here is where the multi-threading is performed on the
    # list of urls (i.e. to_search)
    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=threads) as executor:
        for response in executor.map(make_request_return_url, to_search):
            final_list_of_clearn_urls = clean_remove_duplicate(response, final_list_of_clearn_urls, MAIN_DOMAIN)
            
            
    t1 = time.time()
    print(f"Elapsed time was {t1-t0} seconds ")
```